# Switch only executing one statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I was debugging an application for a java class and my switch statement when changed in case 39 to make intPos 62 instead of 63 no longer works. Instead of printing the console output in all cases it now only gives it for the last case in the switch statement. the code for the class with the switch statement is as follows.

```
public class NWSFB
{
    /** A class variable containing the Station Weather */
    private String strWeather ;
   /** The Constructor */
     public NWSFB(String strVar)
     {
       strWeather = strVar;
     }
  /** A method that finds the station */    
  public String getStationID(String strVar)
  {
    String stationId = strVar ;
    return stationId.substring(0,3);
  }      
 public String getWindInfo(String strAlt)
 {
   String strRet;
   strRet = "The altitude weather for " + strAlt + "000 feet is " +     getAltitudeWeather(strAlt) 
       + "\nWind Direction:" +getWindDir(strAlt) +"0 degrees"
       + "\nWind Speed:" +getWindSpeed(strAlt) + " knots"
       + "\nWind temperature:" +getWindTemperature(strAlt) + "C"
       + "\n. . ."
       + "\n";


   return strRet;
 }

 private int getPos(String strAlt)
 {
   int intAlt;
   int intPos =0;
   intAlt = Integer.parseInt(strAlt);
   switch (intAlt)
   {
     case 3:
      intPos = 4;
      break;
     case 6:
      intPos = 9;
      break;
     case 9:
      intPos = 17;
      break;   
     case 12:
      intPos = 25;
      break;
     case 18:
      intPos = 33;
      break;   
     case 24:
      intPos = 41;
      break; 
     case 30:
      intPos = 49;
      break;   
     case 34:
      intPos = 56;
      break;   
     case 39:
      intPos = 62;
      break;  
    }
   return intPos;
 }
 public String getAltitudeWeather (String strAlt)
 {
  int intPosition = getPos(strAlt) ;
  String strPos = strWeather.substring(intPosition, intPosition+7);
  return strPos ;
 }
 //get wind direction
 public String getWindDir(String strAlt)
 {
  String strPos = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
  return strPos.substring(0,2);

 }
 //get wind speed
 public String getWindSpeed(String strAlt)
 {
   String strPos = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
   return strPos.substring(2,4);
 }
 //get wind temperature
 public String getWindTemperature(String strAlt)
 {
   String strPos = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
   return strPos.substring(4,7);
 }


}
```

This is the class using this code

```
public class A19005 
{

    static String  strStationWeather = "SAN 1905 1808+24 1512+17 1209+10 1708-06 2016-16 211831 211941 192652" ;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     //Create the myWeather object
        NWSFB myWeather = new NWSFB(strStationWeather);   
     //use myWeather to get the weather at various altitudes
        System.out.println("Sation ID:   " + myWeather.getStationID(strStationWeather));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("03"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("06"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("09"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("12"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("18"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("24"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("30"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("34"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("39"));
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get
The altitude weather for 39000 feet is  192652 
Wind Direction:210 degrees
Wind Speed:19 knots
Wind temperature:41 C
. . .

Instead of getting this information for all altitudes like i did when case 39 incorrectly had

```
intPost =  63
```

How do I make my code work so it prints out the weather output for all altitudes instead of just the last one?

EDIT: Just figured out some more information the reason it works when the last case is 3 instead of 2 is because it doesn't compile the last case in all situations when the case39 is executed its the only case to run

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok I was having problems before posting a question when I made it shorter and left out a key part of the code so I just put everything here what part is excessive and not needed?

Comment: Where is the "default" in your switch statement?

Comment: I dont have a default in the statement since I only pass values defined in it I tried adding one                                default:
System.out.println("error");
break;                                                             and nothing changed I'm also not sure how to format code in comments since enter submits the comment and doesn't make a new line

Comment: First, comments aren't meant to house large tracts of code.  Edit your main question to put the new code into that.  Second, I don't see anything wrong with your switch statement.   Could it have been a mistyped value?

Comment: I'm hunting through my code looking for one but don't see any mistyped values anything specific I should look for that would make only the last part of my switch statement work like this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the problem - just copied the code in a file, compiled and run it... The results are at the end, and I get results for all the altitudes!

```
public class P4 
{
    static String  strStationWeather = "SAN 1905 1808+24 1512+17 1209+10 1708-06 2016-16 211831 211941 192652" ;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     //Create the myWeather object
        NWSFB myWeather = new NWSFB(strStationWeather);   
     //use myWeather to get the weather at various altitudes
        System.out.println("Sation ID:   " + myWeather.getStationID(strStationWeather));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("03"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("06"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("09"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("12"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("18"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("24"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("30"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("34"));
        System.out.println(myWeather.getWindInfo("39"));
    }
}

class NWSFB
{
    /** A class variable containing the Station Weather */
    private String strWeather ;

   /** The Constructor */
     public NWSFB(String strVar)
     {
       strWeather = strVar;
     }

  /** A method that finds the station */    

  public String getStationID(String strVar)
  {
    String stationId = strVar ;
    return stationId.substring(0,3);
  }      

 public String getWindInfo(String strAlt)
 {
   String strRet;
   strRet = "The altitude weather for " + strAlt + "000 feet is " +     getAltitudeWeather(strAlt) 
       + "\nWind Direction:" +getWindDir(strAlt) +"0 degrees"
       + "\nWind Speed:" +getWindSpeed(strAlt) + " knots"
       + "\nWind temperature:" +getWindTemperature(strAlt) + "C"
       + "\n. . ."
       + "\n";

   return strRet;
 }

 private int getPos(String strAlt)
 {
   int intAlt;
   int intPos =0;
   intAlt = Integer.parseInt(strAlt);
   switch (intAlt)
   {
     case 3:
      intPos = 4;
      break;
     case 6:
      intPos = 9;
      break;
     case 9:
      intPos = 17;
      break;   
     case 12:
      intPos = 25;
      break;
     case 18:
      intPos = 33;
      break;   
     case 24:
      intPos = 41;
      break; 
     case 30:
      intPos = 49;
      break;   
     case 34:
      intPos = 56;
      break;   
     case 39:
      intPos = 62;
      break;  
    }

   return intPos;
 }

 public String getAltitudeWeather (String strAlt)
 {
  int intPosition = getPos(strAlt) ;
  String strPos = strWeather.substring(intPosition, intPosition+7);
  return strPos ;
 }

 //get wind direction
 public String getWindDir(String strAlt)
 {
  String strPos = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
  return strPos.substring(0,2);
 }

 //get wind speed
 public String getWindSpeed(String strAlt)
 {
   String strPos = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
   return strPos.substring(2,4);
 }

 //get wind temperature
 public String getWindTemperature(String strAlt)
 {
   String strPos = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
   return strPos.substring(4,7);
 }
} 

/* Output:
Sation ID:   SAN

The altitude weather for 03000 feet is 1905 18
Wind Direction:190 degrees
Wind Speed:05 knots
Wind temperature: 18C
. . .


The altitude weather for 06000 feet is 1808+24
Wind Direction:180 degrees
Wind Speed:08 knots
Wind temperature:+24C
. . .


The altitude weather for 09000 feet is 1512+17
Wind Direction:150 degrees
Wind Speed:12 knots
Wind temperature:+17C
. . .


The altitude weather for 12000 feet is 1209+10
Wind Direction:120 degrees
Wind Speed:09 knots
Wind temperature:+10C
. . .


The altitude weather for 18000 feet is 1708-06
Wind Direction:170 degrees
Wind Speed:08 knots
Wind temperature:-06C
. . .


The altitude weather for 24000 feet is 2016-16
Wind Direction:200 degrees
Wind Speed:16 knots
Wind temperature:-16C
. . .


The altitude weather for 30000 feet is 211831 
Wind Direction:210 degrees
Wind Speed:18 knots
Wind temperature:31 C
. . .


The altitude weather for 34000 feet is 211941 
Wind Direction:210 degrees
Wind Speed:19 knots
Wind temperature:41 C
. . .


The altitude weather for 39000 feet is  192652
Wind Direction: 10 degrees
Wind Speed:92 knots
Wind temperature:652C
. . .
*/
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted this code into my IDE and still am only getting the result for the last altitude do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: @AlexChapp - your IDE is somehow confused.  Close your IDE.  Now, from the command line, recompile all files using `javac` and run it using `java`.

Comment: Made a new project from scratch copy pasted my code and it works now so you right that somehow my IDE got confused